# Decompose a table into many columns by the value of one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table which contains a series of temperature measurements, taken with different sensors:

```
timestamp | sensor | temperature
--------------------------------
1.0       | a      | 10
1.1       | b      | 20
1.2       | c      | 30
2.0       | a      | 11
2.1       | b      | 19
2.2       | c      | 32
...
```

What I want is a table like this:

```
timestamp | a    | b    | c
---------------------
1.0       | 10   | Null | Null
1.1       | Null | 20   | Null
1.2       | Null | Null | 30
2.0       | 11   | Null | Null
2.1       | Null | 19   | Null
2.2       | Null | Null | 32
```

In my case, there are many sensors a,b, ... z and over time more sensors can be added.

I need a query which I do not need to adjust if new sensors are added. So SQL should do something like:

1. Scan the table and find all sensors (a,b,c,d ...)
2. return a result table with as many columns as there are sensors (+ timestamp column)

The result table will have as many rows as the input table, and one more  column than there are distinct sensors (for the timestamp).

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what an "automatic" solution means? Does that mean your solution needs to account for the requirement of adding additional sensors over time without changing the initial table structures?

Comment: I want a SQL query which I never need to change, even if more sensors are added. I want SQL to: 1. scan the table for all sensors. 2. create a column for each sensor and fill in a row for each measurement.

Comment: Are you suppose to design the table(s) being queried? Or, are the table design(s) fixed? To me, the table design begs to be refined.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to redesign this? There are many sensors (hundreds) and most of them exist only for a limited amount of time (days). So adding a new column for each sensor is not an option. If I query a short time interval (a week), the temporary table I asked for in my post would only contain the sensors for which measurements exist in the selected time-frame.

Comment: MySQL do not support PIVOT - so only stored procedure with dynamic SQL will help.

Comment: For table 1, use just the three (3) columns (timestamp, sensor, temperature) as shown in your first table. An optional second table can have two (2) columns (sensor, description) to define a foreign key relationship to the senor column of table 1. So only sensors defined in Table 2 can have temperature entries in Table 1. For generating results, use the GROUP BY clause to group the output by timestamp or sensor values.

Comment: Look [this topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213820/150107).

Comment: Thank you for the link Akina, this seems like what I want, just more complicated than expected. And @JohnH, I don't see how this would give me the expected result. If I understand you correctly, then the second table you suggest simply adds more complexity.

Comment: The second table is a means of validating sensor values for row inserts into the first table.

Comment: @steffen You already have a single table that can support your variable number of sensors.  What is the maximum age of any data you want to keep in this table?  Days, Weeks, Months or Years?  What you are proposing would take significantly more rows of data (storage space) than your current design.  Please post TEXT result of SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname; you are using today.

Comment: @Wilson My intention is not to change the underlying table design, I think it is appropriate. The data needs to be available for years. The pivot table I want to generate should be the result of some kind of SELECT statement, I do not want to change the way the data is actually stored on disk. My application is to display the result in a Grafana dashboard.

Comment: ```SHOW CREATE TABLE temperatures; CREATE TABLE `temperatures` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `temperature` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sensor` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_temperatures_sensor_timestamp` (`sensor`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21536191 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1```

Comment: Thanks for your SCT for temperatures. Are you aware your use of datatype timestamp will cause your application to consistently fail in Feb, 2038 (18 years away) due to date range maximum.  Use of datetime datatype would correct this problem and give you the opportunity use a natural selection of mydatetime between begdt and enddt when needed.  Does Grafana dashboard have a API you could feed your selected data to and let Grafana do the pivot handling?

Comment: Grafana does not offer such an option to the user, I would have to dive into the grafana code for mysql... Thank you for all your input, I think I will try to find a different solution